# Tetris - how to prevent I Tetramino from going over the edge - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, tetris

I'm building a Tetris game and I've been stuck for days now.

I have a function to rotate the tetraminos `rotateRight()`.
I built in a way to check if the tetramino is on either edge of the playfield area, and when rotating block goes over the edge (appearing on the other side) it will then move the block one space to left(if its by the right edge and vice versa if its by the left one).
Its done via conditionals code here below:

```
 if (checkEdgeL) { // checks if its by the left wall
    if (checkEdgeR) { // check if it goes over the wall to the other side
      if (current === tetraminosArray[6][currentRotation]) {
        if (currentRotation === 2) {
          currentPosition = currentPosition + 2;
        } else if (currentRotation === 0) {
          currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
        }
      } else if (
        current === tetraminosArray[random][currentRotation] &&
        random !== 6
      ) {
        if (currentRotation === 2) {
          currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (checkEdgeR) { // checks if its by the right wall
    if (checkEdgeL) { // check if it goes over the wall to the other side
      if (current === tetraminosArray[6][currentRotation]) {
        if (currentRotation === 2) {
          currentPosition = currentPosition - 1;
        }
        if (currentRotation === 0) {
          currentPosition = currentPosition - 2;
        }
      } else if (
        current === tetraminosArray[random][currentRotation] &&
        random !== 6
      ) {
        if (currentRotation === 0) {
          currentPosition = currentPosition - 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  draw();
  console.log(currentRotation);
}
```

I have few problems here. When only half of the above is enabled (so only checks for either left or right side) all works fine.

In current state I Tetramino is pulled from one side to the other due to conditionals and how code moves blocks when they go over the edge.

If I change to `else if` statement in the middle whole thing is messed up:

```
 if (checkEdgeL) {
    if (checkEdgeR) {
      if (current === tetraminosArray[6][currentRotation]) {
        console.log("conditional 1");
        if (currentRotation === 2) {
          console.log("conditional 2a on the left");
          currentPosition = currentPosition + 2;
        } else if (currentRotation === 0) {
          console.log("conditional 2b on the left");
          currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
        }
      } else if (
        current === tetraminosArray[random][currentRotation] &&
        random !== 6
      ) {
        if (currentRotation === 2) {
          currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (checkEdgeR) { // CHANGED HERE TO ELSE IF CONDITIONAL instead of two separate IF's
    if (checkEdgeL) {
      if (current === tetraminosArray[6][currentRotation]) {
        console.log("conditional 1");
        if (currentRotation === 2) {
          console.log("conditional 2a on the right");
          currentPosition = currentPosition - 1;
        }
        if (currentRotation === 0) {
          console.log("conditional 2b on the right");
          currentPosition = currentPosition - 2;
        }
      } else if (
        current === tetraminosArray[random][currentRotation] &&
        random !== 6
      ) {
        if (currentRotation === 0) {
          currentPosition = currentPosition - 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  draw();
  console.log(currentRotation);
}
```

So question is: Is there a way of making it work as if one half of the code was commented out, and vice versa?

My whole tetris is available in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/WebPotato/pen/bGxQEEr).

It's set up to only spawn I Tetraminos now, and timer is off so blocks don't slide down like in the proper game.

Any help greatly appreciated, before I pull all my hair out.

I've tried changing conditionals from `if` to `else if` but that would just mess my game even more.

Comment: Is there ever a case where checkL and checkR can both be true?

Comment: Technically its true on both sides as when block goes over the edge appears on the other side. But I have no clue how would I trigger one without triggering the other. At least not with with set-up I have.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you’re struggling with, but at the same time I think your code could be much simpler (while simultaneously fixing your problem). Why do you need to check if it’s on the left AND on the right in the same **if** statement? Why don’t you just write something like this: **if (checkEdgeL) [put on the right side - 1]; else if (checkEdgeR) [put on the left side + 1]**

Comment: It was my initial setup, but this way it wasn't working as intended - after full rotation it just moved the blocks again pushing it one space too far for some reason.

I know my code is probably hacky as hell, but I'm still very much a noob.